# Django 1.8 migrations output

Tags: django, django-1.8

Is there a way to recreate the same output of the migration as when first created. For example:

```
Output:

Migrations for 'blog':
0001_initial.py
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Post
```

So after **migrate** can we interrogate the migration file to re-produce this useful output?

Comment: You can do it yourselves

Comment: All migrations will be kept in a folder called `migrations` underneath your app in the document structure of the django project. You can open any of those migration files in a text editor and manipulate as you wish.

Comment: i know i can, but had a few to interrogate and wanted to pull out these summary information

Comment: You can roll back your migration and re run them with `migrate app_name zero`. Note that this should only be done on a local env as you will lose the data in the DB.

Comment: Understood but wanted to just extrapolate this summary information without rolling back.